# Javascript: Get the month and year in div when change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this JavaScript that change the month

To develop , I thought to create a router and load all my html templates with respect to router value. The body section of my index.html files looks like

And the month change **HTML** :-

```
<INPUT type="button" name="previousMonth" id="previousMonth" value='previous' onClick="getCalendar('previousMonth')" class="previous-button">
<INPUT type="hidden" name="month" size="2" value="<?php echo $m; ?>" id="month" class="input-month" onBlur="getCalendar()">Month
<INPUT type="button" NAME="nextMonth" id="nextMonth" value="next" onClick="getCalendar('nextMonth')" class="next-button">
```

And the year change **HTML** :-

```
<INPUT type="button" name="previousYear" value="previous"  id="previousYear" onClick="getCalendar('previousYear')" class="previous-button">
<INPUT type="hidden" name="year" id="year" size=4 value=<?php echo $a; ?> class="input-year" onBlur="getCalendar('')" >Year
<INPUT type="button" name="nextYear" value="next"  id="nextYear" onClick="getCalendar('nextYear')" class="next-button">
```

**JavaScript** :-

```
function getCalendar(action){
    document.getElementById('ajaxResponse').innerHTML = "<div align='center' style='padding:5px'><img src='js/ajax-loader.gif'></div>";
    var month=document.getElementById('month').value;
    var year=document.getElementById('year').value;
    if (month == "" || month > 12){
        month = 1;
    }else if (month < 1){
        month = 12;
    }
    if (year == ""){
        var d = new Date();
        year = d.getFullYear();
    }
    if(action == "nextMonth" || action == "previousMonth"){
        if(action == "nextMonth"){
            newMonthValue = parseInt(month) + 1 ;
            document.getElementById('month').value = newMonthValue;
        }else if(action == "previousMonth"){
            newMonthValue = parseInt(month) - 1 ;
            document.getElementById('month').value = newMonthValue;
        }
        if(newMonthValue > 12){
            document.getElementById('month').value = 1;
        }else if(newMonthValue < 1){
            document.getElementById('month').value = 12;
        }
        var actionMonth=document.getElementById(action).value;
    }else if(action == "nextYear" || action == "previousYear"){
        if(action == "nextYear"){
            newYearValue = parseInt(year) + 1 ;
            document.getElementById('year').value = newYearValue;
        }else if(action == "previousYear"){
            newYearValue = parseInt(year) - 1 ;
            document.getElementById('year').value = newYearValue;
        }
        if(newYearValue < 1){
            document.getElementById('year').value = 1900;
        }
        var actionYear=document.getElementById(action).value;
    }
    var ajax = new GLM.AJAX();
    var url='calendarAjax.php?month='+month+'&actionMonth='+actionMonth+'&year='+year+'&actionYear='+actionYear;
    ajax.callPage(url, showSubscribeResult, "GET"); 
}
```

How can i put the month name behind the month number, and month Arabic.

Comment: What does getCalendar') do ?

Comment: its get me a number of month